# How to arrange k items in N ways with equal probability

Tags: combinations, permutation, probability

I have 7 items, k1-k7 and I want to arrange them in 30 different ways with each item appearing in each position with equal probability.

```
k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7

k1, k4, k5, k3, k7, k6, k2

.

k6, k2, k7, k1, k5, k4, k3
```

I am not able to understand which is the method to achieve this. Please let me know which algorithm will work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then these thoughts should work for you:

There are `7! = 5040` possible ways to arrange your elements.
Out of these `5040` unique sequences there are `6! = 720` of them that have `k1` at the first position, `720` have `k2` at the first position, ..., `720` have `k1` at the last position, ... and so on.
So, if you randomly draw `30` from these `5040` sequences, I think the result should meet your requirements.

How to draw them? Well, that depends on the programming language you are using. In C++ there is [`next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation). In python there is [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). These functions will iterate through all `7!` possible arrangements in a lexicographical order. Other languages may offer similar tools.

Then, you can randomly generate a number `n` in `[0, ..., 5040[` and call `next_permutation` `n` times on the initial range (or, in python, advance the iterator `n` times). Repeat this 30 times.
Note however, that for bigger number this can quickly become very inefficient, not sure what your needs are regarding efficiency.

### Update

The more I think about my solution, the more i realize that *How to draw them?* can be answered much better:

All you need is a [uniform shuffle algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47338/whats-a-uniform-shuffle). This will by definition uniformly generate one of the `7!` permutations which is exactly what my original answer does, but it will be much more efficient and much simpler to code as most languages provide such a shuffle algorithm (e.g. [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)).

I will keep my original answer because it helps me (and hopefully others) to understand why a uniform shuffle is the correct solution here.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa glad to hear that :) please read my update

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt would be take one random element out of the list, next take a random element form the subset of not chosen elements and so on. For the second subset do the same and when done, check if its equal the first subset. Due to uniform distribution of good random function it should give you equal probabilities

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, at least not as stated in the description. If `k_1` was to have the same probability of appearing at each position, then the number of combinations where it appeared at position 1 would equal the number of combinations where it appeared at each of the other positions. But that means that the number of combinations would have to be a multiple of 7, which 30 is not.

If you only care about the probability when you draw the 30 combinations, then randomly choosing the sequence is the way to go, as Brueni suggests. However this has nothing to do with there being 30 combinations, so I doubt this is what you intend?

Comment: There are two different ways to look at this: If you have 10 numbers and you *don't know* their values, you just know that they were "created" by rolling a dice, then you still do know that each number from 1 to 6 has equal probability (`1/6`) of appearing at each position (even though 10 is not a multiple of 6), because you know for each position the dice has been rolled. This changes however, if you additionally *know* that the dice rolled 3 ones. Then, the probability of having a one at a certain position is of course `3/10`.